# Spring parse multiple parameters into object

Tags: html, spring, forms, httprequest

I have quite complicated html form with multiple rows that contains multiple values. I would like to receive data as object with list inside spring controler.

Example link:

```
?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param1=value4&param2=value5&param3=value6 etc...
```

Controler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/config_add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView configAddSubmit(Form form)
```

Form class

```
class Form
{
    List<String> param1;
    List<String> param2;
    List<String> param3;

    setters and getters here    
}
```

The only way I could find working is to add name index in html form so link looks like:

```
?param1[0]=value1&param2[0]=value2&param3[0]=value3&param1[1]=value4&param2[1]=value5&param3[1]=value6 etc...
```

The problem is that user can change form dynamically using js, add new row, delete row or change its position so indexes may mixed up. It is very important to maintain rows order inside controler. Html forms send it in right order but spring controller can not parse it without indexes.